# Annotate pdf in real time (android and pc)

Tags: pdf, file-synchronization, pdf-viewer, pdf-editor

What app can I use to annotate pdfs and view the annotations in real-time?

Basically I would like to annotate a pdf on dropbox on my android and be able to view the changes on my PC on an instantaneous basis.

Comment: What do you mean by "tool"? You mean an app? And when you say "PC" you mean Dropbox website on your PC in the browser? Or you mean a second, Windows based "tool"?

Comment: @Ryan yes I mean app and just viewing Dropbox website on my pc  unless dropbox doesn't sync in which maybe evince or something?

Comment: So you have an Android app that does this? Now you are looking for a Windows app? Or both?

Comment: @Ryan looking for both